# System of algebraic equations concerning rates

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, word-problem

I'm not even sure where to start on the problem. **Is this possible to solve without logarithms?**

"A certain type of bacteria doubles every 6.5 hours. If there were 60 bacteria to start with, what is the hourly growth rate of the bacteria? How many bacteria will there be after a day and a half? Solve using algebra."

Comment: What do you know about geometric progressions. That could be somewhere to start.

Comment: Can you write down a formula that expresses the fact the the population doubles in $6.5$ hours?  That seems like the place to start to me.

Comment: $\ t = b2^{t/20} $?

Comment: After $t$ hours there are $60\cdot2^{x/6.5}$ bacteria.  Does that help?

Comment: What other equation do I have to write from there?